# Python: Why this code I built is not using all the three M0 values within the initial list? (Magnetization x Temperature - Weiss Theory)

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, numerical-methods, transcendental-equation

I'm trying to evaluate (using a numerical approach to solve a transcendental equation) how much does the number of iterations vary as I change the value of my initial guess M0. I think I should not expect it to return the same amount of iterations for so different values of M0, so I think that this code might not using all these three values I want it to.

```
#ITEM C:
import numpy as np

Tc = 1.0
T = list(np.arange(0.01,1.2,0.001))
M0 = [0.5,50.,100.]
erro_min = 1e-6

for k,Mk in enumerate(M0):
    
    erro = 1.
    iteracao = 0
        
    if k == 0:
        print('\nc) Com critério de convergência dado por {}, alteramos agora os valores de chute inicial para o processo de solução da eq. autoconsistente. A intenção é avaliar possíveis mudanças nas quantidades de iterações.\n\n--> Para M0 = {} tínhamos:'.format(erro_min,Mk))
    else:
        print('\n--> Para M0 = {} temos'.format(Mk))    

    for n, Tn in enumerate(T):

        while erro > erro_min:
        
            iteracao += 1
            M = Mk
        
            a = M
            b = np.tanh(Tc*M/Tn)
        
            if abs(a - b) > erro_min:
                Mk = b
            else:
                break
   
    print("\nNúmero de iterações: {}".format(iteracao))
```

I tried to use/include `for k in range(3):` inside the `for n, Tn in enumerate(T):` but before `while` process, but it apparently gets one specifically value obtained for M(T) for both k = 1 and 2.